# Python: Store Float value in list

Tags: python

I want to store 1.00000 in a list and the list should iterate 1047 times. Anyone knows how to store 1.00000 at all places in a list using loop.?

I have tried this code:

```
print(len(data))

for content in range(1,len(data)):
  globals()[content.append(1.00000)]
```

and I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "G:\Setups\Python\chi-1.py", line 24, in <module>
>       globals()[content.append(1.00000)]
>   AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is good that you have tried. So, please post it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :

```
>>> lst = [1.00000 for x in range(0, 1047)]
>>> len(lst)
1047
```

if you want list that contains string `'1.00000'` use `format(1.000000, '.5f')`

```
>>> lst = [format(1.000000, '.5f') for x in range(0, 1047)]
>>> len(lst)
1047
>>> lst
>>>['1.00000', '1.00000', '1.00000', '1.00000', '1.00000', '1.00000', '1.00000', '1.00000', '1.00000'......]
```

Comment: I tried this. It worked Thanx.

But now when i print the content of list. It only displays 1.0 and not 1.00000

Help with this too..!

Comment: Change 1.00000 to "1.00000", since I believe you want a str instead of a float

Comment: I don't want string. I want to store 5 decimals points in a list

Comment: You can only keep one zero after the decimal point, after that, you can't have more of them, 1.0 is the same as 1.00000. That is how float *works*, no matter how hard you try, you will never be able to keep 5 zeroes after the decimal and keep it as a float. Otherwise, you're looking for a str instead

Comment: @ForamKalyani : `1.0` is equvalent to `1.00000` or `1.0000000000` its same as it round off to `1.0`

Comment: @ForamKalyani, Python (by default) tries to reduce clutter when printing floats. You can print them with different precision using `format`, but the internal representation of `1.0` is exactly the same as `1.00000`. The number of decimals you entered is not preserved anywhere.

Comment: So if I subtract any float number from 1.0 will it give answer?

for example 1.0 - 0.56565

Comment: Yes, have you not tried it yet? An easy to understand example is to compare python doing math with a calculator, you never will have to type 1.00000 - 0.56565 in a calculator, instead you type 1 - 0.56565, this goes the same with python. Excepted for division

Comment: got it Thanks for help

Comment: @ForamKalyani : the answer will be same for `1.0` or for `1.0000`

Comment: Hi @ForamKalyani : if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can "multiply" lists in Python. Multiplication is an implicit loop:

```
lst = [1.0] * 1047
len(lst)
#1047
```

Comment: Tried this too.. It also worked But it displayed same 1.0 only even When i multiplied 1.00000 instead of 1.0.

Comment: There is no difference between 1.0 and 1.0000. It is the same number.